# Implementing MATLAB compiler SDK example in C

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-compiler

I am trying to run the MATLAB compiler  sdk example given in this link in C.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/cxx/integrate-a-c-shared-library-into-an-application.html

I have created the shared library files and MATLAB runtime application. To implement it, I created a new project in VS 2019 and included the `matrix.c` as source file. My runtimme is saved in matlab trial folder, runtime in v910 folder. In the project settings, I have made these changes

1. VC++ Directory-> library directories-> `D:\matlab trial\v910\extern\lib\win64\microsoft`;
2. C++ directories-> additional include directories->

   D:\matlab trial\librarytrial (my c shared library is saved in this folder)
   D:\matlab trial\v910\extern\include
3. Linker-> Additional library dir ->

   `D:\matlab trial\librarytrial; D:\matlab trial\v910\extern\lib\win64\microsoft; D:\matlab trial\v910\bin\win64;`

Linker->input-> `libmatrix.lib` (cshared library ),
included all the lib files in the runtime library folder

Added `D:\matlab trial\v910\runtime\win64` to my environment path.

When I compile the code it says
"the code execution cannot proceed because mclmcrrt9_10.dll was not found".

This file is in `D:\matlab trial\v910\runtime\win64`. This path I already included in my environment path.

What to do in this case?

Comment: I don’t see that directory mentioned under either “1. VC++ Directory-> library directories” nor “3. Linker-> Additional library dir”.

Comment: @Chris sorry I forgot to include it in my question. I did add that directory in the linker->additional library dir. But still it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling VS helped solve this issue.